# Share bloc across different routes

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm trying to share same bloc across two routes.
But when I come back from second route the bloc get automatically disposed so in the first route I find myself with all the stream closed.

For example this is the first route (HomePage) where I instantiate the bloc, download a list from api and show it in the build method.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


  GroupsBloc _groupBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies(){
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _groupBloc = GroupsBloc();
    _groupBloc.getAll();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _groupBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Then I navigate to a second screen where I can add an item to the list.

```
  _onAddGroupPress(){
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => BlocProvider<GroupsBloc>(bloc: _groupBloc, child: GroupPage()),
        fullscreenDialog: true
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the second screen I retrieve the bloc and I use it to add an item, then I go back to Home Page.

```
class GroupPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _GroupPageState createState() => _GroupPageState();
}

class _GroupPageState extends State<GroupPage> {

  FormBloc _formBloc; //another bloc
  GroupsBloc _groupBloc;


  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies(){
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _formBloc = FormBloc();
    _groupBloc = BlocProvider.of<GroupsBloc>(context); //retrieve of the bloc 
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _formBloc?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
  }
```

In the dispose method of the second screen I dispose only _formBloc bloc but _groupBloc gets disposed too, so when I come back in the first page I found myself with _groupBloc disposed and all it's stream closes.

I tought of passing the bloc to the second screen as a props but I don't know if it's the right way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It obviously depends on the scope of your Bloc, but there is nothing preventing you from sharing the same instance throughout your whole app.

ie. simply wrap your whole MaterialApp inside `BlocProvider<GroupsBloc>(bloc: _groupBloc, child: MaterialApp( ... ))`

if "groups" are not global to your app, you should probably just pass the bloc along to the second widget.

Comment: That was so simple :) Thank you @herbert. I wrapped MaterialApp with groupBloc and now it's working. By the way do you think that `_onAddGroupPress(){
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => GroupPage(bloc: _groupBloc),
        fullscreenDialog: true
      ),
    );
  }` is a good practice?

Comment: @FabrizioTognetto imho definitely better than the previous where you had a BlocProvider inside the page route builder.. but if your app allows it, i think it would be even better if you don't need to pass the bloc along at all.. something like `push( ... ).then((Group newGroup) => bloc.create(newGroup)` ie, using navigators "return value" (navigator.pop(`newGroup`) in the dialog) so the dialog does not even need to know about the bloc..

btw. if this solved your problem, please accept the answer :-)

Comment: this solution may work fine, but it does not describe WHY the _GroupsBloc is being garbage collected given that the home page is still in memory and still has a reference to it.  Something is not right here ....